# How to decode the encoded values in base64 format in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

How to decode all the encoded values in base64 format in a file?
Below is the File contents where the encoded vaule startswith `MTAu` i need to decode them.

```
SN: ols.com.,ptr=dc
PTR: ols.com
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjMzLjQ=
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjM1LjQ=
oncur: MTAuMzMuMzUuMTE0

SN:  pls.com.,ptr=dc
PTR: pls.com
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjMzLjQ=
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjM1LjQ=
oncur: MTAuMzMuMzUuMTE0

SN: qls.com.,ptr=dc
PTR: qls.com
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjMzLjQ=
oncur: MTAuMTIzLjM1LjQ=
oncur: MTAuMzMuMzUuMTE0
```

What I tried:

```
import base64

with open('testFile') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "MTAu" in line:
            ln = base64.b64decode(line)
            print(ln)
```

When i ran the above code it gives the type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decod4.py", line 7, in <module>
    ln = base64.b64decode(line)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

While trying with command line testing it works:

```
>>> import base64
>>> line="MTAuMTIzLjMzLjQ="
>>> base64.b64decode(line)
b'10.123.33.4'
```

Desired output:

```
SN: ols.com.,ptr=dc
PTR: ols.com
oncur: 10.123.33.4
oncur: 10.123.35.4
oncur: 10.123.33.114

SN:  pls.com.,ptr=dc
PTR: pls.com
oncur: 10.123.33.4
oncur: 10.123.35.4
oncur: 10.123.33.114
```

any help / direction Will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to clean up the line a bit, and you are trying to decode the entire line not just the encoded string. Try this:

```
with open('testFile') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'MTAu' in line:
            dec_str, enc_str = line.split(':')
            ln = base64.b64decode(enc_str).decode()
            print('{}: {}'.format(dec_str, ln))
        else:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: salparadise, This works great in terms of value decoding but with `line.split()` it decodes value and print that but i need the prefix as well..`oncur: 10.123.33.4`

Comment: salparadise, Its throwing `ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Comment: @krock1516 sorry, try it with the new edit. if it still doesn't work, please post an update with what you currently have.

Comment: this works but  rest of the file contents it doesn't print , sorry about the confusion if any. I'm updating my post with desired output , hope that will give the clue.

Comment: @krock1516 try it with the else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166180/discussion-between-salparadise-and-krock1516).